# Wordpress theme customization (CSS)

Tags: css, wordpress

i'm having trouble customizing my wordpress theme. If you see in http://www.arqui9.com, in the footer area, the contacts are above the facebook widget. I want to change that, i want the contacts below the facebook widget.
I tried change the position and margin top attribute in the #footer .fr element, to no success.

Both of the elements (contacts and facebook widget) belong to the footer element:

```
#footer {
clear: both;
position: relative;
background: transparent url(...) no-repeat center 0;
color: #888;
margin-top: 90px;
```

The contacts belong to the following element with the following css:

```
#footer .fr {
width: 220px;
position: relative;
font-size: 12px;
margin-top: 10px;
```

And finally the facebbok widget is on the following element:

```
#footer .column {
float: left;
width: 210px;
margin: 0 0 5px 20px;
}
```

any ideas on how i can change the position of the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move

```
<div class="fr">
    <a title="" href="http://www.arqui9.com"><img id="logosmall" src="http://www.arqui9.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/LogoSMALLER.png" alt=""></a>
     <p>Copyright © 2012 Arqui9 - Visual+3D,<br>
        All Rights Reserved - pfernandes@arqui9.com</p>
</div>
```

to go below the last "column" div.

see http://jsfiddle.net/qQaxM/

Comment: It didn't occur to me just making the simple change. I think i got carried away thinking on a css solution. Thanks a lot!